# How to find the URI for the File in assets folder xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a video placed in Assets folder of android

```
Assets/LanguageResource/MyVideo.mp4
```

How to find the `URI` for the asset file

```
private void startVideo()
        {
            //Creating MediaController
            mediaController = new MediaController(this);
            mediaController.SetAnchorView(video);
            video.SetMediaController(mediaController);
            video.SetVideoURI(uri);
            video.RequestFocus();
            video.Start();
        }
```

Comment: For the resources folder, it's just the name and Xamarin will find it by itself. Try "MyVideo.mp4" as the path, maybe that works for assets too.

Answer (score 4):

The `URL` for the asset file should be like this: `file:///android_asset/one.mp4`.

And you can get the `AbsolutePath` of the file for example like this:

```
var file = new File(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("file:///android_asset/one.mp4").ToString());
var uri = file.AbsolutePath;
```

And assets added to your project will show up just like a file system that can read from by app using [AssetManager](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Content.Res.AssetManager/).

If you want to access the stream of this file, you can check the official document like this: [Using Android Assets](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_6_-_using_android_assets/).

**Edit:**

Sorry, problem is that we cannot play video from assets folder, you need to load it from raw/ resource folder.

Comment: Still getting file not found exception, Resource is also marked as android asset .

Comment: @Devrath, are you sure that your video's build action is `AndroidAsset`? Strange thing, I've tested this code.

Comment: @Devrath, o, sorry, I found the problem, the file can be found with that url, problem is that playing the .mp4 file from \assets is not possible, you must load it from \raw folder. I need to edit my answer.

Comment: I placed in `RAW` folder, Absolute Path returns `"/file:/android_asset/androidvideo.mp4"` .... Still i get the `file not found exception`.... What have you marked the resource as `AndroidResource` or `AndroidAsset`

Comment: @Devrath, for row/ resource folder, the path is different, you can try this path: `Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.yourvideo`, and the build action should be `AndroidResource`.

Answer (score 0):

You can able to find a file from AssetManager of android and get a stream of file directly.

**like var br = new BinaryReader(Application.Context.Assets.Open("LanguageResource/MyVideo.mp4");**